# SQL Server Pivot table

Tags: sql-server, pivot

I need to make a pivot table. I have 3 columns (organization name, weekday (monday to sunday) and action (sell, buy, create, destroy etc)), how do I create a pivot table so that it would show counts of every action per organization for every week day?

This is as close as I could get:

```
SELECT *
FROM [AdventureWorksDW2012].[dbo].[Testine]
PIVOT (COUNT (Tipas) 
       FOR Diena 
       IN 
       ([Monday],[Tuesday],[Wednesday],[Thursday],[Friday],[Saturday],[Sunday])) 
       AS KiekiaiPerDiena
```

It shows counts of total actions per organization for every day, so I basically need to expand to show counts per every action, not count of total actions.

Comment: What are your desired results -- 1 row for each organization with lots of columns (1 column for every day/action)?

Answer (score 0):

Here's one way to do it using `COUNT` with `CASE` -- difficult to use `PIVOT` for this sort of functionality.

```
SELECT 
  Org,
  COUNT(CASE WHEN Tipas = 'buy' AND Diena = 'Monday' THEN 1 END) Monday_Buy_Cnt,
  COUNT(CASE WHEN Tipas = 'sell' AND Diena = 'Monday' THEN 1 END) Monday_Sell_Cnt,
  COUNT(CASE WHEN Tipas = 'create' AND Diena = 'Monday' THEN 1 END) Monday_Create_Cnt,
  COUNT(CASE WHEN Tipas = 'buy' AND Diena = 'Tuesday' THEN 1 END) Tuesday_Buy_Cnt,
  COUNT(CASE WHEN Tipas = 'sell' AND Diena = 'Tuesday' THEN 1 END) Tuesday_Sell_Cnt,
  COUNT(CASE WHEN Tipas = 'create' AND Diena = 'Tuesday' THEN 1 END) Tuesday_Create_Cnt,
  ...
FROM Testine T
GROUP BY Org
```

[SQL Fiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/a7abc/3)

And then you can add the rest of the actions/days accordingly.  Gets a little long, but should work.

If you need multiple rows per organization per action, then add that to your group by and remove from the CASE statements.  For example:

```
SELECT 
  Org,
  Tipas,
  COUNT(CASE WHEN Diena = 'Monday' THEN 1 END) Monday_Cnt,
  COUNT(CASE WHEN Diena = 'Tuesday' THEN 1 END) Tuesday_Sell_Cnt,
  ...
FROM Testine T
GROUP BY Org, Tipas
```

[Another Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/a7abc/6)